# Can this be further optimised

Tags: c#, optimization

```
public static bool IsDivisible(double p, double n, double r, double k)
    {
        double x = p;
        double a = 0.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0;
        while (x <= n)
        {
            a += Math.Floor(n / x);
            if (x <= r)
                b += Math.Floor(r / x);
            if (x <= k)
                c += Math.Floor(k / x);
            x *= p;
        }
        return a > b + c ? true : false;
    }
```

This above code checks if a nCr is divisible by a number p.k is n-r.
This function returns true if a particular nCr is divisible a number p.Can this be optimised further.

Comment: Although it is not an optimization, `a > b + c` is already returning what your method should return, so you can simply do `return a > b + c`

Comment: i would like to add one more thing here... you must not use double to do your calculations but instead use decimal type. Decimal will precise your results. Also declare your variables correctly - double a = 0.0m;

Comment: @DnshPly9 I don't think switching to `decimal` will be an optimization.

Comment: @marlon yes! it is not about optimization but about precision. There are probably more changes that the conditions of =, < or other will not match correctly with double than they would with decimal. Decimal must be the choice when doing arithmetic operations. for eg. 1.02 + 2.43 may not equal 3.45 when using double whereas will always be 3.45 when using decimal. In such cases comparision starts failing. That's why decimal is good. Definitely not fast than double. And i dont know how much precision matters in the code above. :)

Comment: @DnshPly9 No, the OP wants faster code. Read the comment below Mark Byers' answer. Switching to `decimal` will be slower... not by magnitudes, but it is *slower*. That's heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Marlon I agree to you..my bad...thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are your inputs are always positive integers? If so, then you can improve performance using `int` instead of `double` and using integer division instead of floating point division. Then you also won't need to call `Math.Floor` as integer division automatically truncates the result for you.

You can also simplify the last line to just this:

```
return a > b + c;
```

Comment: ok..done that.Can it be optimized further.Or rather any other way of writing this code so that it runs faster